# How do I preserve whitespace when passing parameters from one script to another, if I'm executing one of those scripts remotely using ssh?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, quoting

I'm having trouble passing parameters with whitespace from one bash script to another bash script that will be run remotely with ssh. I have one script, create-node.sh that looks like this:

```
# create-node.sh
#!/bin/bash

function set_node_env_variables {        
    docker-machine ssh remote-machine 'bash -s' < ./set-env-variables.sh \
        $ENV_VARIABLE_ONE \ # "foo bar"
        $ENV_VARIABLE_TWO \ # feefi
        $ENV_VARIABLE_THREE \ # "fo fum"
        $ENV_VARIABLE_FOUR # huffpuff        
}
```

create-node.sh passes parameters to set-env-variables.sh, which is run remotely using ssh and looks like this:

```
# set-env-variables.sh
#!/bin/bash

i=0
argv=()

for arg in "$@"; do
    argv[$i]="$arg"
    i=$((i + 1))
done

echo "export ENV_VARIABLE_ONE=${argv[0]}" >> /root/.profile #expected: "foo bar"; actual: foo
echo "export ENV_VARIABLE_TWO=${argv[1]}" >> /root/.profile #expected: feefi; actual: bar
echo "export ENV_VARIABLE_THREE=${argv[2]}" >> /root/.profile #expected: "fo fum"; actual: feefi
echo "export ENV_VARIABLE_FOUR=${argv[3]}" >> /root/.profile #expected: huffpuff; actual: fo
```

Environment variables with spaces or special characters are stored with double quotes on the machine that will execute set-env-variables.sh using ssh, otherwise I'm not using quotes at all.

How do I preserve whitespace when passing parameters from create-node.sh to set-env-variables.sh, if I'm executing set-env-variables.sh remotely using ssh?

Comment: "...I'm not using quotes at all" . That's a bug. You'll need to (at least) surround all variable names (`$VAR1`) with dbl-quotes, ie. `"$VAR1"` . Good luck.

Comment: Unfortunately surrounding the variable names I'm passing as parameters with quotes is still not preserving whitespace.

Comment: Escape character "\" before space ?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's rewrite `set-env-variable` to simplify it. (Really, it's doesn't set anything; it just generates a script that can set environment variables, but we'll ignore that.) You don't need to create `argv`; you can use the positional parameters directly.

```
#!/bin/bash

{
  printf 'export ENV_VARIABLE_ONE="%q"\n' "$1"
  printf 'export ENV_VARIABLE_TWO="%q"\n' "$2"
  printf 'export ENV_VARIABLE_THREE="%q"\n' "$3"
  printf 'export ENV_VARIABLE_FOUR="%q"\n' "$4"
} >> /root/.profile
```

(Use `%q` to make sure the value of the variable is quoted correctly for use in a command. For example, a value that contains a double quote needs to have it escaped so that it doesn't incorrectly close the double quotes in the `export` command: `export foo="hi\"there"` versus `export foo="hi"there"`.)

Next, make sure you quote your expansions correctly in the function (and, there is no need to read the script from standard input; just pass it as the first argument to `bash`):

```
set_node_env_variables () {        
    docker-machine ssh remote-machine \
      bash ./set-env-variables.sh \
           "$ENV_VARIABLE_ONE" \
           "$ENV_VARIABLE_TWO" \
           "$ENV_VARIABLE_THREE" \
           "$ENV_VARIABLE_FOUR"        
}
```